# Gridsearch on convolutional autoencoder input shape value error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, wrapper, autoencoder, grid-search

I tried to optimize a convolutional auto encoder with grid search. Unfortunately I am running in an error that I don't really understand and where I get stuck. The error is written below, it seems that there is an error with the shape, but I don't get it. The whole code is written below and can be run since it downloads the mnist-dataset directly.
I would appreciate any help and thank in advance!
Best regards MAGY

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Laden des MNIST-Datensatzes und Vorbereitung
(train_images, _), (test_images, _) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255.0
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255.0
train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (len(train_images), 28, 28, 1))
test_images = np.reshape(test_images, (len(test_images), 28, 28, 1))

# Funktion zur Erstellung des Autoencoders
def create_autoencoder(optimizer='adam', encoding_dim=32):
    input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

    # Encoder
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    # Decoder
    x = Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

    autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')
    return autoencoder

# Wrapper, um das Autoencoder-Modell mit GridSearchCV zu verwenden
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_autoencoder, verbose=0)

# Hyperparameter-Raster definieren
param_grid = {
    'optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd'],
    'encoding_dim': [32, 64]
}

# Rastersuche durchführen
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3)
grid_search.fit(train_images, train_images)

# Beste Kombination von Hyperparametern anzeigen
print("Beste Kombination von Hyperparametern:")
print(grid_search.best_params_)

# Autoencoder-Modell mit den besten Hyperparametern erstellen
best_autoencoder = create_autoencoder(
    optimizer=grid_search.best_params_['optimizer'],
    encoding_dim=grid_search.best_params_['encoding_dim']
)

# Autoencoder trainieren
best_autoencoder.fit(train_images, train_images, epochs=10, batch_size=128)

# Autoencoder auf Testdaten anwenden
decoded_images = best_autoencoder.predict(test_images)

# Beispiel: Anzeigen eines Originalbildes und des rekonstruierten Bildes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 10  # Anzahl der Bilder zum Anzeigen
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # Originalbild
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(test_images[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # Rekonstruiertes Bild
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_images[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
plt.show()
```

ValueError:
All the 12 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

### Below are more details about the failures:

12 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 729, in _fit_and_score estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 246, in fit raise ValueError("Invalid shape for y: " + str(y.shape))
ValueError: Invalid shape for y: (40000, 28, 28, 1)

I checked the test_images.shape which is (10000, 28, 28, 1) and not (40000,28,28,1)